# LengthValidator not firing for non-mandatory fields

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, validation

I have created a DB driven form via JSF.  Based on DB values, a field might be mandatory, and it might have a max number of characters.  These requirements are independent of one another.  A field can be mandatory with no max length or be NOT mandatory but still have a max length.

```
HtmlInputTextarea input = new HtmlInputTextarea();
if(validation != null && validation != ""){
    LengthValidator lengthVal = new LengthValidator();
    lengthVal.setMaximum(Integer.parseInt(validation));
    input.setValidatorMessage("Please enter a valid number of characters");
    input.addValidator(lengthVal);
}
```

validation is the max number of characters allowed.  In the logs I can see that for the necessary field, that validation is showing the correct values.  But when I submit the form, the lengthvalidator only fires on fields that I have deemed Mandatory.  Below is the mandatory field code:

```
input.setRequired(true);
input.setRequiredMessage("Please enter a value for this field.");
input.setImmediate(true);
HtmlMessage message = new HtmlMessage();
message.setFor(inputId);
message.setStyleClass("errorMessage");
div.getChildren().add(input);
div.getChildren().add(message);
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Where are you adding the validator?**

```
input.addValidator(new YourValidator());
```

Add this, and the validation will always be fired.